# Node js mysql syntax error

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I write some code in the server-side, in node js for update MySQL database.

this is my code:

```
exports.addPlayerToMatch = function(uid,matchId){
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
        dbFunctions.getPlayerUids(matchId).then(function(rows){
            playerUids = JSON.parse(rows[0].uids_of_players);
            playerUids.push(uid);
            console.log("new player uids: " +playerUids);
            numberOfPlayers = playerUids.length;
            db.query('UPDATE current_matches SET number_of_players = ?, 
uids_of_players = ? WHERE id = ?' ,[numberOfPlayers,playerUids,matchId], 
function (err, rows) {
                if (err){ console.log("ErrorForAddPlayerToMatch: "+err);}
            });
            resolve(numberOfPlayers);
        }); 
    }); 
};
```

and this is the error:

> ErrorForAddPlayerToMatch: Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your 
>   SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''3d8b7210fc1999bf191b0e1f7d744269' WHERE id = 29' at line 1

I have no idea !!

help, please.

Comment: `playerUids` is array. I'm not familiar with js, but I suppose string representation of array breaks sql query text.

Comment: oh yes. I forgot to stringify the array before adding it to query. I knew it should be a simple mistake.

Comment: You can answer your own question, btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem was that I forgot to turn an array into a JSON object again before using it in the query.

it will solve with something like this:

```
var playerUids = JSON.stringify(playerUids);
```

and then use it in the query.